# Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686

Tags: gdb, centos

CentOS 6.2 + GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-50.el6)

When I debug a simple c++ code with GDB, I saw the following warning:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
```

I have tried the following methods and none of them fix the problems:

1. Search SO
2. `yum install glibc`
3. `debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686`

In fact, when I install those RPM one by one, I just realized that they are installed already.

```
[root@localhost Excluded]# rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686 is already installed
[root@localhost Excluded]# ls *.rpm
glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686.rpm  libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm
[root@localhost Excluded]# rpm -ivh libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 is already installed
[root@localhost Excluded]# rpm -ivh libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm 
warning: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 is already installed
    file /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 from install of libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
```

Why GDB cannot find it?

**Question**: Do I have to worry about this issue? If not, how to turn it off? If yes, how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I have installed CentOS 5.6 and 5.8. Both have no such an issue.

Comment: debuginfo-install didn't work for some reason. This fixed it for me: sudo yum --nogpgcheck --enablerepo=debug install glibc-debuginfo

Comment: somewhat related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148652/5510

Answer (score 108):

`debuginfo-install` is a command of `yum-utils`, so

1. `yum install yum-utils`
2. `debuginfo-install glibc`
3. if the warning's still there, edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo`, set `enabled=1`

Comment: I definitely had to enable the CentOS-Debuginfo.repo. Thanks.

Comment: You'll also need to set `gpgcheck=0` in `CentOS-Debuginfo.repo` ([source](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories)).

Comment: I had to Enable the Repo i.e Step 3 to do Step 2 ! Thanks thought .

Comment: For dnf, `sudo dnf install dnf-plugins-core` as per https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121318, then `sudo dnf debuginfo-install ...`

Comment: if someone know how to do Step 3 in RHEL7? i have only epel.repo, epel-testing.repo, redhat.repo files

Comment: How to do it on ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right track. FYI, if your gdb error message includings something like `Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install httpd-2.2.15-55.el6.centos.2.x86_64` don't ignore it. Quit DGB and install the debuginfos it recommends. I had to install the ones for apache, php and mysql for my LAMP box.

Comment: If you don't have the `debuginfo` repo defined in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/DebugInfo helped me out.

Comment: Worked for me on Fedora 31 (did not need to do step 3).

Comment: Doing 1, 2, and then 3 did not work. I then did 1, 3, set `gpgcheck=0` in `CentOS-Debuginfo.repo`, and then redid step 2 and it worked. Using CentOS 8

Answer (score 1):

In case, someone else encounters the same issue,

I had updated the glibc and somehow the old ldconfig had been flushed 
was facing this error while running the application

> error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Even after setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it didn't work:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Finally the commands below came to the rescue.

```
// Add you library path here.
echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf

// And then Run ldconfig to reflect the path
ldconfig
```

Comment: This looks like it's what I need to solve my problem, but can you make it clearer what you're suggesting I do?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

I followed some tips in the comments and here's what I tried and succceded in my fresh install CentOS 7.2

1. From @lkraav's comment,  I followed this wiki https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/DebugInfo and create a new file.

> The following could be appended to `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` or a new file created such as `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debug.repo`.

2. I pasted those contents from the wiki into the new `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debug.repo` file but edit `enabled=0` line to `enabled=1`
3. I `debuginfo-install` everything showed in the gdb warning and succeeded installing.