# "Missing separate debuginfos" in non-root account

Tags: gdb, redhat

I have the same problem as reported here:

[Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.i686 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389988/missing-separate-debuginfos-use-debuginfo-install-glibc-2-12-1-47-el6-2-9-i686)

However, I am not the root user so I can't just run  `debuginfo-install ...`. I was wondering if there's a relatively easy way for me to get these libraries and add a Path to them in my home directory without using a root account.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, though I'm not sure I would call it easy.  The essential idea is to install the files in your `$HOME` and then tell gdb how to find them.

The steps are like:

1. Download the RPMs.
2. Install them somewhere in `$HOME`.  Sometimes you can do this with `rpm -i --prefix=...`, though I don't know if that will work for debuginfo RPMs.  You can always extract the files from an RPM using `cpio`.  Be sure to preserve the directory names.
3. In gdb, use `set debug-file-directory` to tell gdb to look at your new directory.  You can put multiple directories here by separating them with `;`.

Some more fiddling with source directories (see `dir`) might be needed after this.

It's maybe worth noting that you normally don't actually need system debuginfo.