# Line number and file location is not displayed in gdb in c

Tags: c, gdb

I did not find file location and line number in gdb when I open the curedump.
Even the path of source file is correct and compiled with -g option

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

    #0  0x090ae019 in VlanIsFrameTagged ()

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.10.1-2.i686 libgcc-4.4.0-4.i586
(gdb) b
Breakpoint 1 at 0x90ae019
(gdb) bt

     #0  0x090ae019 in VlanIsFrameTagged ()
     #1  0x090aeb8a in VlanGetTagLenInFrameForLocalPort ()
     #2  0x09083947 in VlanGetTagLenInFrame ()
```

Comment: And you didn't `strip` the debug information from the program? And you're using the correct program (the one with debuginfo) when running GDB?

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct program and coredump when running with gdb. It seems coredump is corupted.

Comment: Did you write the listed functions, or are they from the library?  Have you run the 'debuginfo-install' command that GDB recommends running?  (See also: [Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389988/missing-separate-debuginfos-use-debuginfo-install-glibc-2-12-1-47-el6-2-9-i686).)

Comment: Does `addr2line -e /path/to/executable 0x090ae019` output anything?

Comment: # addr2line -e ../ISS.exe 0x090adbc1
    >>>>>>  Output : ??:0

Comment: Can you run `nm ./ISS.exe | grep VlanIsFrameTagged` ? I'd like to see if VlanIsFrameTagged  is defined in that executable. If not, it may be in a shared library and we'll need to track it down and see if that was compiled with line number information.  Also, what compiler are you using, and what operating system?