# Java Heap Dump error - Metadata does not appear to be polymorphic

Tags: java, heap-dump, invocationtargetexception

I get this Stacktrace when trying to take a heap dump from a running Java process. What causes this and what do I have to do to make a proper heap dump?

```
Dumping heap to dump.bin ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Metadata does not appear to be polymorphic
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.types.basic.BasicTypeDataBase.findDynamicTypeForAddress(BasicTypeDataBase.java:278)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualBaseConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualBaseConstructor.java:102)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Metadata.instantiateWrapperFor(Metadata.java:68)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.DictionaryEntry.klass(DictionaryEntry.java:71)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.Dictionary.classesDo(Dictionary.java:66)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary.classesDo(SystemDictionary.java:190)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary.allClassesDo(SystemDictionary.java:183)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeClasses(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:942)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.write(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:427)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.run(HeapDumper.java:62)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:83)
    ... 6 more
```

Environment: CentOS 64 bit, Java OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Using `ps` to see the java version that is used:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-1.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

My first try was:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-1.b13.el6_6.x86_64/bin/jmap  -dump:format=b,file=dump.bin 14984
```

That got me :

```
14984: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

So I ran with the `-F` option

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-1.b13.el6_6.x86_64/bin/jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=dump.bin 14984
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same version of Java and they're both 64 bit? And running it with the same user ?

Comment: Maybe related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1417962

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

I was running the `jmap` command as `root`, but I had to run as the user that started the java process.

In my case:

```
sudo -u robau ./jmap -dump:format=b,file=/tmp/dump.bin 14984
```

Seems to be related to this JDK bug:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075773

Comment: there is a nice built-in heap file analyser jhat /tmp/dump.bin that will analyse heap dump file and expose results on port 7000

Comment: If you tried with the `-F` flag before, don't forget to remove it when running with the right user, otherwise you can still have problems.

Comment: If you still get the same error, try installing the package mentioned by Big Pumpkin and run this command.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue with trying to run jmap on an AWS ElasticBeanstalk instance. The command that fixed it was

`sudo debuginfo-install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

BTW, jmap was installed on the AWS ElasticBeanstalk instance with command

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.91-0.b14.10.amzn1.x86_64`

Comment: I had this issue even when I ran the command as the process user. This answer helped me.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue on CentOS even when running as the user that started the process. What solved it for me was installing the debuginfo package corresponding to the package supplying the jmap utility.

To install the debuginfo package, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194583/1122288) (substituting your java package for glibc). It requires getting/using the debuginfo-install utility, and making sure the [CentOS-Debuginfo.repo](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) is set up correctly and enabled.

Comment: Same problem on CentOS 7 too. I downloaded the package from http://debuginfo.centos.org/7/x86_64/ and manually installed it using `rpm -ivh java-1.8.0-openjdk-debuginfo*.rpm`. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, I resolved this issue by installing the openjdk-dbg package:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-dbg
```

I now suspect that this resolved my issue indirectly by upgrading the jdk to a version that corrected the bug.  You might be able to resolve this issue with:

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8
```

**Note:** After java is upgraded, you must restart the java process in order to get a proper dump.  If you don't, you will get something like this:

```
Attaching to process ID 21957, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.UnmappedAddressException: 7f21453c9bf8
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.checkPage(PageCache.java:208)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.getData(PageCache.java:63)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readBytes(DebuggerBase.java:225)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCInteger(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:498)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxAddress.getCIntegerAt(LinuxAddress.java:69)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.getLongValueFromProcess(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:604)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.readVMTypes(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:164)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.<init>(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:89)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupVM(HotSpotAgent.java:395)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:83)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Does this work *because* the jdk is updated? (and thus the JDK bug fixed?)

Comment: Interesting question.  I'll try removing the dbg package and I'll report back what happens.

Comment: Hah, looks like you are right, it still works after removing the dbg package!  I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: what versions are you referring to (pre/post) ?