# How to install libstdc++6 debug symbols on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gdb, libstdc++

For example, take the following minimal example:

```c++
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
#ifdef __GLIBCPP__
    std::printf("GLIBCPP: %d\n",__GLIBCPP__);
#endif
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
    std::printf("GLIBCXX: %d\n",__GLIBCXX__);
#endif
    throw std::runtime_error("Were are libstdc++.so.6 debug symbols?");
    return 0;
}
```

When running it inside my `gdb`, it does not show the debug symbols for `libstdc++.so.6`:

```
$ g++ -o testmain test.cpp -ggdb --std=c++98 && gdb ./testmain
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.1-0ubuntu1) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./testmain...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/Downloads/testmain 
GLIBCXX: 20200408
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Were are libstdc++.so.6 debug symbols?
```

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt f
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
        set = {__val = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29295, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
        pid = <optimized out>
        tid = <optimized out>
        ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x00007ffff7be1859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = ... <stderr>}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x00007ffff7e67951 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff7e7347c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff7e734e7 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff7e73799 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000055555555524a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdef8) at test.cpp:11
No locals.
(gdb)
```

It just shows `No symbol table info available` for the `libstdc++.so.6` frames.

How can I show the symbols for the `libstdc++.so.6`?

Searching on this list https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6, I already tried installing the following packages, but none of them fixed the problem:

1. `libgcc-10-dev:amd64 <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.0`
2. `libstdc++-10-dev:amd64 <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.0`
3. `libstdc++6-10-dbg:amd64 <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.0`
4. `libc6-amd64-cross:all <none> 2.31-0ubuntu7cross`
5. `linux-libc-dev-amd64-cross:all <none> 5.4.0-21.25cross`
6. `libc6-dev-amd64-cross:all <none> 2.31-0ubuntu7cross`
7. `libstdc++6-amd64-cross:all <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross`
8. `libgcc-10-dev-amd64-cross:all <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross`
9. `libstdc++-10-dev-amd64-cross:all <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross`
10. `libstdc++6-10-dbg-amd64-cross:all <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross`
11. `libx32stdc++6-10-dbg:amd64 <none> 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.0`

Related questions:

1. [How do you find what version of libstdc++ library is installed on your linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac)
2. [/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

---

#### Update 1

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libstdc++6
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                              10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libstdc++6-10-dbg-amd64-cross                 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross1           all          GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debug build) (amd64)
ii  libstdc++6-7-dbg:amd64                        7.5.0-6ubuntu2                        amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debug build)
ii  libstdc++6-amd64-cross                        10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross1           all          GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (amd64)
```

#### Update 2

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libstdc++6
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                              10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libstdc++6-10-dbg:amd64                       10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debug build)
ii  libstdc++6-10-dbg-amd64-cross                 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross1           all          GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debug build) (amd64)
ii  libstdc++6-amd64-cross                        10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04cross1           all          GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (amd64)
```

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install libstdc++6``` maybe fixes the problem

Comment: Check what package provides your libstdc++6 and install the corresponding "-dbg" package. For Ubuntu 20.04 it should be libstdc++6-7-dbg or libstdc++6-10-dbg

Comment: @Botje , How can I check which package provides my `libstdc++6` ? I already have installed `libstdc++6-7-dbg`, `libstdc++6-10-dbg` and `libstdc++6`, but the problem persists.  I updated the question with the output of `dpkg --list | grep libstdc++6`

Comment: That output says your libstdc++ is 10.2.0, so logically you must install the libstdc++6-10-dbg package, which is not yet installed according to your dpkg output. That -amd64-cross package you installed is used for cross-compiling.

Comment: @Botje , Now I run `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-10-dbg` and updated the output of `dpkg --list | grep libstdc++6` on the question. But when I run my program, it still not showing the symbols on the stack frame.

Comment: FYI it's a stack _trace_

Comment: Why do you need them? If you are debugging libstdc++, you probably should have it built from sources, and only link to the debug version when actually debugging it. Otherwise, every single C++ program on your machine will use the debug build of libstdc++, which will more likely than not slow it down to a grinding halt.

Comment: To see the ower of a mutex, and they are probably required to see the message of std::exception, and other low-level structures.

Comment: gdb can print values of stdlibc++ structures, low level or otherwise, just fine without libstdc++ debug symbols. Can you show a gdb command you want to use and cannot because there are no debug symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Background Story:

Days ago, I was also curious about the same question as yours. But that's on `CentOS`.

[What can I do differently after I install those missing debug info packages for gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031982/what-can-i-do-differently-after-i-install-those-missing-debug-info-packages-for)

You can check the question to see what I learnt during searching, I solve your question with those prior knowledge.

In short, for the same thing, in `CentOS` the difficulties come down to installing the debug info packages. Because the `gdb` in `CentOS` tells what exact version of some debug info files you need to install and it gives the full command.

```
debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
```

But this command just can't work and you need to manually [add some package sources to install that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65031770/5983841) .

However, as soon as you succeed installing the debug info packages, everything else is set up nicely, **even the source files**! You can `s` step into e.g. `abort()` and `list` around the source code!

---

In `Ubuntu`:

1. You have to find the exact version of your `libstdc++.so.xxx` and install the corresponding debug info files.
2. No libarary(e.g. `libstdc++`) source files will be installed and set up after install the corresponding debug info files packages. But you can manually do it with `set substitute-path`.

#### Answer Part:

I made my `gdb` work under `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`. I think that may applies to yours too.

1. I assume you know this https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html .

So firstly I `ldd my.a.out`.

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbfa6f84000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbfa697b000)
...
```

In my Ubuntu, reading debug symbol for `libc.so.6` is successful. So I want to check both `.so` files' `.gnu_debuglink` section.

`libc.so.6` is a link to `libc-2.27.so`

so I read the above section with `readelf -x.gnu_debuglink libc-2.27.so` and gives me:

```
Hex dump of section '.gnu_debuglink':
  0x00000000 6c696263 2d322e32 372e736f 00000000 libc-2.27.so....
  0x00000010 32e033a0                            2.3.
```

This means its debug info file's name is `libc-2.27.so`, which exists in `/usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory.

Now check `libstdc++.so.6`, which is a link to `libstdc++.so.6.0.25` in my machine.

`readelf -x.gnu_debuglink libstdc++.so.6.0.25` gives:

```
Hex dump of section '.gnu_debuglink':
  0x00000000 31313961 34346139 39373538 31313436 119a44a997581146
  0x00000010 32306338 65396438 65323433 64373039 20c8e9d8e243d709
  0x00000020 34663737 66362e64 65627567 00000000 4f77f6.debug....
  0x00000030 30573da0                            0W=.
```

This `119a44a99758114620c8e9d8e243d7094f77f6.debug` is a build-id debug file.

2. Learnt from your question and comments below, I do `dpkg --list | grep libstdc++` and shows

```
ii  libstdc++-7-dev:amd64                      7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04                             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++-8-dev:amd64                      8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04                             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                           8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04                             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libstdc++6:i386                            8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04                             i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

So I `sudo apt install libstdc++6-8-dbg`.

Then I used `dpgk-query -L libstdc++6-8-dbg` to see what files are installed with this packages.

```
tianhe@tianhe-windy:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ dpkg -L libstdc++6-8-dbg
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/debug
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f2
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f2/119a44a99758114620c8e9d8e243d7094f77f6.debug
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++fs.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/gdb
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-8-dbg
```

And I think I got the debug files when I saw this line:

`/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f2/119a44a99758114620c8e9d8e243d7094f77f6.debug`.

Then I open `gdb` again and it works. I can now `s` step into `string s = "hello";`.

So try check what I describe above see if they match.

Answer (score 4):

I followed these instructions https://www.hiroom2.com/ubuntu-2004-dbgsym-en/.

Adding the debug symbols repo:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e

U=http://ddebs.ubuntu.com
C=$(lsb_release -cs)

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
deb ${U} ${C} main restricted universe multiverse
#deb ${U} ${C}-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb ${U} ${C}-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb ${U} ${C}-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

wget -O - http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dbgsym-release-key.asc | \
    sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update -y
```

Then install symbols for `libstdc++6`

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-dbgsym
```

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to @Rick's answer.

In ubuntu 20.04+, you need to install `libstdc++6-dbgsym`, and before this you need to add debug symbol repo to apt.

To get the source code, you should run `apt source libstdc++6`, then run `./debian/rules patch` as described in `debian/README.source`.

(Personally I feel installing debug info and source code in ubuntu is much more complex than centOS. I suggest you to use centOS if you just want to have a look into libstdc++'s source code.